# Redirecting to the same page with different redirect parameters in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

This page I'm making basically takes in the user request for the date and will do some a select query on that date (however the db part is not important). There's a textbox (txtDate) and a button (setDate) used to redirect to the same page with the string in txtDate as the Date parameter in the URL. On PageLoad, I want to take the current QueryString[Date] and put it back in txtDate (so the user can see what date is selected), however, it automatically will request the old QueryString whenever I set that textbox to the new one I'm requesting.  It's baffling me.

This is the Page_Load:

```
    String dateInput = null;
    dateInput = Request.QueryString["Date"];
    txtDate.Text = dateInput.Replace("-", "/"); //if I just comment this out, it works perfectly fine
```

And this is the button click:

```
    String s = null;
    s = txtDate.Text.Replace("/", "-");
    if (s == "") //if empty sends the current date
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?Date=" + DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
    }
    else //sends the users date
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?Date=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s));
    }
```

I don't know if I'm explaining this very well, but it works like this:

3/14/2016 in current Date parameter

Put new date in txtDate: 03/16/2016 and hit setDate button

Redirects back to 3/14/2016 when and only when I set txtDate.Text to the current parameter (03/16/2016), otherwise it correctly redirects to the new Date parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a long time since I tried WebForms but if I'm right you need to check if it's a Postback before updating your textbox.

So basically just wrap your

```
txtDate.Text = dateInput.Replace("-", "/"); //if I just comment this out, it works perfectly fine
```

inside an

```
if (!Request.IsPostback)
{
    txtDate.Text = dateInput.Replace("-", "/"); //if I just comment this out, it works perfectly fine
}
```

To wrap things up... what's happening here is just your Page_load event is firing twice. First tour for your button_click event and then second tour for your Redirect. When your button clicked you take query parameter and set it to your textbox before your querystring change. So that's why all working fine if you delete that line. All you need to do is checking whether it's a postback or not.

Comment: Thank you! It was just !IsPostBack but you sent me in the direction I needed.  Appreciate it!